# google d8 (v8 shell) navigation on Mac (arrow keys) do not navigate

Tags: console, v8

I'm using the v8 console (d8) on a Mac after installing it via `brew install v8`. Let's say I type something like:

```
const a = {};|
```

(where | is the cursor) - I want to move the cursor back so that it's in between the curlies, like so:

```
const a = {|};
```

But, when I press the back button, I get:

```
const a = {};^[[D^[[D
```

... Is there a way to fix this or even a key combination I can use to navigate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature you're looking for is called "readline support", named after the library that provides it. d8 does not currently have such support. Thankfully, there's a handy tool named `rlwrap` that emulates readline support for arbitrary interactive terminal programs. Installing that and then running d8 as `rlwrap d8` should give you what you want :-)